# Exisiting Live email account to access application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a MVC app where I want users to login using their Windows Live email account. Any ideas how to proceed? Show code...

Comment: "Show code"? As in "do this for me"? I think not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to integrate your site with Windows Live for authentication.

[Dan Wahlin has an article: "Integrate Windows Live ID Authentication Into Your Website"](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/08/17/integrate-windows-live-id-authentication-into-your-website.aspx). I'll bet there's code there! The article is from 2007, so YMMV with how current the APIs are.

Here's how you get started: [Microsoft's article: Use Windows Live ID for Your Web Site](https://msm.live.com/app/)